# Assign to constant variable in a constructor?

Tags: c++, initialization, constants

In C++ how do I make a variable constant but assign to it in a constructor? The reason I want to do this is because I'm trying to use data driven design by putting all my data into an XML file and then loading that data into variables. The problem is that I can't load the values in a initialization list so I have to do it in the constructor (or elsewhere), but then the variables aren't constant.

Here's an XML file:

```
<weapons>
    <pistol>
        <damage>5.0</damage>
        ...
    </pistol>
    ...
</weapons>
```

Then I've got a class like:

header

```
class Weapon
{
public:
    Weapon();
    const float damage;
};
```

source

```
#include "Weapon.h"
Weapon::Weapon()
{
    //load damage value into damage variable
}
```

Because the damage variable is constant I can't do anything with it in the constructor, only in the initializer list, but obviously I can't execute code like reading an XML file in the initializer list. So even though the variable will never change should I just not make it constant or is there a proper way to leave it constant and do what I need?

Comment: Why can't you execute code like that in the initializer list?  Just write a free standing function (preferably in the an anonymous namespace in Weapon.cpp) which parses out the damage value and returns it.  Then you can call that function in the initalizer list when initalizing the damage variable.  Oh, and please make it private.

Comment: Yeah I actually didn't even consider that check out my comment to the accepted answer. And yeah I'll make it private.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is this weird colon-member syntax in the constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a xml parser, for example:

```
class WeaponXMLParser
{
public:
   WeaponXMLParser(const std::string& filename);
   float getDamage();
};
```

Initialize const member in initializers list:

```
Weapon::Weapon(const WeaponXMLParser& wxp) : damage(wxp.getDamage())
{
}
```

Comment: Didn't think I could call a function to return a value in a intializer list. Guess I was wrong when I said "obviously I can't execute code like reading an XML file in the initializer list".

Answer (score 2):

Use an initializer-list:

```
#include "Weapon.h"
Weapon::Weapon() : damage(3.4)
{
}
```

Comment: The question literally said "The problem is that I can't load the values in a initialization list". This is missing the bit where the initializer expression is a function call doing the load, instead of a mere compile-time constant.

Answer (score 0):

The body of the constructor indeed runs too late, your `const` members already have a value. that comes from the *initializer list* :

```
Weapon::Weapon()
  :  damage(0.0f) // 0.0f is the default value
{
}
```

In your case, you'd have to get it from the XML file, e.g.

```
float Weapon::LoadDmgFromXML();
Weapon::Weapon()
      :  damage(LoadDmgFromXML())
{
}
```

Comment: Still value-initialized, 8.5/7 says "(possibly cv-qualified)" i.e. cv qualifications make no difference. And that in turn means zero-initialized for non-class non-array types, which finally means 0 (zero), taken as an integral constant expression, converted to float. But that didn't fit in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use a "builder" class. So in your case you might have WeaponBuilder with appropriate methods that lets you do this:

```
WeaponBuilder wb(xmlFilename);
Weapon w(wb);
```

Then everything will be available in Weapon's constructor, so that you can make appropriate things const.

Answer (score 0):

you must do it in initializer list. And you can provide a function that will determine what damage is and returns it, so you can set your const variable:

```
class Weapon
{
public:
    Weapon():damage(damage_xml()){}
    const float damage;
private:
    float damage_xml();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use const_cast and make a non-const reference to the const variable.

```
float &_damage = const_cast<float&>(damage);
_damage = 12.34;
```

Comment: This is undefined behavior. -1

Comment: And have your program crash and burn.